# Check Shopify variant stock from variant ID in JavaScript with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, shopify

I've created a JQuery script that has multiple selector forms to narrow down a complicated multi-sku product in Shopify.

By the time the customer has selected everything, the shopify variant IDs are returned as variables via an array (not getting data directly from Shopify).

e.g.

```
var idone = "15065378226219"
var idtwo = "13367973249067"
```

Now I want to use these values to get the variant inventory quantity. I've tried this code

```
function getValues(callback) {
   $.getJSON("/admin/variants/15065378226219.json",function(result){
     callback(result);    // this should be the return value
   });
}


 getValues(function(values) {
   alert(values);
});
```

But the alert doesn't do anything, so I don't think anything's happening. My goal is to get the variant inventories for both IDs so I can validate in JS whether or not the product is available (both IDs have inventory greater than 0).

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: If that is client side code, running on what might be a customers computer on the front-facing part of your site, '/admin'-type urls probably won't work at all.

Comment: A url like this will be what you want to use probably: ''/products/<product-handle>.js''

Comment: I see – is it therefore possible to go directly to variant or will I have to call the parent product data then search for the variant ID I need?

Comment: Probably have to get the whole parent product and pull the variant data out

Comment: It's not possible to get a variant directly through the front-end. You'll have to get the data through the parent product - though on the upside, if most of your variants belong to the same product, you'll be saving a few AJAX calls if you're getting all the data at once

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far! OK, so I've tried: 

 ` jQuery.getJSON('/products/product-handle-goes-here.js', function(product) {
  alert(product.variants);
} );`

But it just seems to return option-option. Any ideas how to get an array containing variant ids and corresponding inventory quantities?

Answer (score 0):

When you access your complex product in Liquid, there is a filter that shows the product off as JSON. Amazingly, this filter is 'json'. So try this Liquid:

```
var fizzborked = {{ product | json }};
```

You can inspect that in a comment, or however you wish. Look for your variants. Note the inventory quantity being there. Use that to build your logic. You can no longer make callbacks to Shopify for inventory amounts. 10 years ago people were complaining about having their inventory levels scraped, so Shopify cut that off.

As far as more sophisticated approaches go, you could always use a private App to support a Proxy call, allowing you to make secure Ajax calls to cull whatever data you need to support your use-case. Win Win!

Comment: Thanks David – the variants I'm trying to get data from aren't from the product located on the current page, but from another product. Is there a way to specify which product to get the data from using the example you posted?

Comment: You would be smart to assign those other products supporting the one current from a collection. That would allow you to smartly get them, in Liquid. You are not the first person to try and roll your own bundler... I did mine 10 years ago... with that, you are good to go.